# How to change disabled in Button when the state changes React

Tags: reactjs, button, use-state

I have a form. If all fields are not filled, the button, that send this form is disabled. So, the user should fill all fields if he s/he wants to send the form.

So, I change state, when the user fill inputs. But the button does not change the color if all inputs are filled.

```
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState(1);
  
  const disabled =
    activity === "" && type === "" && participants <= 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Also when you say `const disabled = activity === "" && type === "" && participants <= 0 ? true : false;`, whenever only one of this requirements sufficient, it will be false, so then button will be active? It doesn't look true. Also `participants <= 0` part is false in initial, so then your button will be active again in initial?

Comment: Try adding  `activity === "" && type === "" && participants <= 0` directly to the button's disabled attribute

Answer (score 0):

Mehmet Pekcan, thank you for prompt. I rewrite activity === "" || type === "" || participants <= 0 ? true : false

Comment: you have to share your code which involve: setActivity, setType, and setParticipants, i want to see the condition / event that changes the state, (share your forms markup and the handlers)

Comment: const [activity, setActivity] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState(1);

  const openModal = useSelector(
    (state) => state.serviceReducers.suggestionModal
  );
   const changeInput = (event) => {
    setActivity(event.target.value);
  };
  const changeSelect = (event) => {
    setType(event.target.value);
  };
  const changeParticipants = (event) => {
    setParticipants(event.target.value);
  };

Comment: can you tidy that up and edit it into your question?